# 2004 Dodge Neon Sxt Terrible Gas

Tags: neon

Hi I have a 2004 Dodge Neon Sxt that has terrible gas mileage (174,880 miles; holds 6-6.5 gallons per full tank refill about $25 to fill). No matter what speed I go it eats gas and supposedly to get 20-25 mpg. But I drive 12 miles one way and i burn quarter tank. What could be causing my gas problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be to connect a [diagnostic tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=obd%20reader) to the [OBD port](https://www.google.com/search?q=obd%20port%20dodge%20neon) to check if there are any stored error codes in the ECU. Bad gas mileage is often caused by a malfunctioning sensor somewhere, which OBD can usually tell you.

Comment: Is it possible its bad spark plugs? A mobile mechanic told its my spark plugs and wiring... Should that be something I should look at? If so how?

Comment: It can be a lot of things, but since you didn't mention anything about rough running or problems in cold/moist conditions the spark plugs and wiring are not the number one suspect.

Comment: Dont all older cars run rough unless you replace its engine?

Comment: @ElijahC. really, is that what you think? You've got a lot to learn. Btw you marked my answer, but did you already have the car checked up?